# Terraform reference looped resources value

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm trying to use a provisioner to write the public IP address of a newly created Azure instance into a file.

I was able to do it for a single instance.

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "helloterraformips" {
    name = "terraformtestip"
    location = "East US"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
    public_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"

    tags {
        environment = "TerraformDemo"
    }
}


resource "null_resource" "ansible-provision" {
depends_on = ["azurerm_virtual_machine.master-vm"]
count = "${var.node-count}"
   provisioner "local-exec" {
    command =  "echo \"[masters]\n ansible_ssh_host=${azurerm_public_ip.helloterraformips.ip_address} \" >> /home/osboxes/ansible-kube/ansible/inventory/testinv"
  }
}
```

Trouble is when I try to the same on VM's created thro Terraform looping, I'm facing issues when trying to access them.

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "mysvcs-k8sip" {
  count                        = "${var.node-count}"
  name                         = "mysvcs-k8s-ip-${count.index}"
  location                     = "East US"
  resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_resource_group.mysvcs-res.name}"
  public_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
}

resource "null_resource" "ansible-provision" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command =  "echo \"[masters]\n${element(azurerm_public_ip.mysvcs-k8sip.*.ip_address,count.index)} \" >> /home/osboxes/ansible-kube/ansible/inventory/inventory"
  }
 }
```

I'm getting this error

Resource 'azurerm_public_ip.mysvcs-k8sip' does not have attribute 'ip_address' for variable 'azurerm_public_ip.mysvcs-k8sip.*.ip_address'

I'm digging into the semantics of Terraform and trying various things, but so far its not working and each iteration to create all resources also takes time. Any help or hint would be very useful.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm don't think this is the whole answer since your error message doesn't agree with this solution, but note that you need to also have `count = "${var.node-count}"` on the `null_resource`, to ensure that you get one instance of that for each instance of the `azurerm_public_ip`

Comment: Good catch, I missed the count int he edit, have updated it now. Seems like this is a limitation in Terraform and I would have to workaround https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/6634

Comment: That issue does look relevant but I'm not sure why, in that case, it would work in the situation where you don't have a `count`. If the problem is that the IP address takes some time to be allocated, you could try initially running terraform with `-target=azurerm_public_ip.mysvcs=k8sip`, thus temporarily ignoring the `null_resource`, and then run Terraform again with no special flags after waiting a little while for the IP addresses to show up, so Terraform can find them when it refreshes. Not ideal, I know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround I was able to do and get this working was to run "terraform apply -target=azurerm_virtual_machine.master-vm" which first creates the VM. Then run terraform apply again which would then run a provisioner which had this

```
resource "null_resource" "ansible-k8snodes"{
  count = "${var.node-count}"

  provisioner "local-exec" {
   command =  "echo \"\n[nodes]\n ${element(azurerm_public_ip.mysvcs-k8sip.*.ip_address,count.index+1)} ansible_ssh_user=testadmin ansible_ssh_pass=Password1234! \"  >>  /home/osboxes/ansible-kube/ansible/inventory/inventory"
  }
}
```

@Martin - Count or no count, it doesn't matter and it fails everytime. Infact, it seems like it worked only once for the single instance code posted above in my question, when I tried it again, it didnt work. Thx for your help.